# SignalR Groups fail when colon in name

Tags: signalr

Question:
Why Groups fail to work when using SignalR?

Check that you are not using a colon in the group name.
That's 4 hours I'll never get back!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid a colon in the group name. Otherwise, Group method calls do not get invoked on the (javascript) client.

There were no errors, no messages in any logs.

Just a silent failure.